# InvalidCastException when running in Windows 7 64-bit but not in XP 32-bit

Tags: c#, com, casting, windows-xp, windows-7-x64

I hope you all can help me. I have a dll that was written in Delphi quite some time ago, so as such it is compatible with XP 32-bit. I have code written in VS2010 in C# with the target as .NET 4.0. I added the dll to the references in VS2010. It works properly in XP but when I try the same exact code in Windows 7 64-bit I get the following error

> Unable to cast COM object of type 'FASTBeamCOM.GPFASTBeamClass' to interface type 'FASTBeamCOM.IGPFASTBeam'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{B7D3D8C1-6919-11D4-8616-9E780E5EC276}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The FASTBeamCOM dll contains the GPFASTBeamClass and the IGPFASTBeam interface. I was able to find out how to register the FASTBeamCOM.dll for 64-bit using the sysWOW64\regsvr32 in administrator mode. However, I don't know what else to do to get this dll to work.

Here is a sample of some code that I used to test the dll in both XP and Windows 7

> ```
>   private static FASTBeamCOM.GPFASTBeamClass f = new FASTBeamCOM.GPFASTBeamClass();
>    public FASTBeamCOM.IGPFASTBeam FB
>    {
>        get { return f as FASTBeamCOM.IGPFASTBeam; }
>    }
> ```

```
   public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int iCopyProtection = 0;
        FB.VerifyCopyProtection(ref iCopyProtection);
        FB.setApplicationName("Wholehouse.dll");
        FB.initializeFB();
        FB.SetProductAvailability();
    }
```

I've tried declaring the FB property as both GPFASTBeamClass and IGPFASTBeam and I get the same error message. The error occurs at the FB.VerifyCopyProtection command. Like I said, it works great in XP 32-bit but not Windows 7 64-bit. I don't know if it's a 32-bit vs 64-bit problem or an XP vs Windows 7 problem.

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.

Comment: First instinct is that its got to be a 32/64 problem. I'm wondering if perhaps the IID really didn't get registered probably (for some unknown reason) even though you registered the server with the wow64 version of regsvr32. You might open up registry editor and look through HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Classes\Interface and see if the IID mentioned in the error messages is present; if it is not, it could suggest that another dependent type library or DLL may need to be registered.